# Rails param is missing or the value is empty: data при редактировании формы. Отправляю пустую форму, почему?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Нажимаю на `edit`, перехожу на `edit/:id` в форме данные, которые редактирую, здесь все нормально, но при отправке возникает ошибка.

Вообще это не единственная ошибка, которая выходила, некоторые пофиксил, но я думаю у меня вообще неправильно составлена форма и пути может быть?

Контроллер:

```
def index
    @datas = Todoist.all
end

def create
    @data = Todoist.new(todos_params)

    if @data.save
        redirect_to todoists_path
    end
end 

def edit 
    @data = Todoist.find(params[:id])
end 

def update 
    @data = Todoist.find(params[:id])

    if @data.update_attributes(todos_params)
        redirect_to todoists_path
    end
end 

def destroy 
    @data = Todoist.find(params[:id])
    @data.destroy
    redirect_to todoists_path
end

private
    def todos_params
        params.require(:data).permit(:todo)
    end
```

Форма edit:

```
 <div>
        <%= form_for @data do |f| %>
          <%= f.text_field :todo, class: 'form-control' %>
          <%= f.submit class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
          <%= button_tag 'Cancel', type: 'button',  id: 'cancel_button' ,class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
        <% end %>
</div>
```

Пути:

```
resources :todoists, only: [:index, :create, :update, :destroy, :show, :edit]
resources :users, only: [:index, :new, :create]
```

Comment: Перепишите все без этого вот `data`. Оно вас путает сильно.

Comment: Посмотрите в логах контроллера, в каком виде прилетают парамсы? Контроллер ждёт от вас хэш с ключом data, то есть `data: { todo: "Название тудушки"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Доброго времени суток.

Не смотря на то, что у Вас переменная экземпляра называется @data, она содержит экземпляр объекта Todoist, поэтому, как мне кажется, в методе todos_params должно быть так:

```
def todos_params
  params.require(:todoist).permit(:todo)
end
```